# Liveliness Probe does not allow http headers

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I am unable to find what the issue is when I introduce the httpHeader component of the liveliness check in deployment file

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
.....
....

livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: "/healthcheck"
    port: 9082
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  httpHeaders:
  - name: x-b3-sampled
    value: 0
  timeoutSeconds: 2
  periodSeconds: 10
```

I am trying to suppress the tracing on the healthcheck. The moment I remove the httpHeaders component the deployment is successful. Otherwise it give the following error

```
[ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].livenessProbe): unknown field "httpHeaders" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Probe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crap!!
Realized httpHeaders should be inside the httpGet.

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: "/healthcheck"
    port: 9082
    httpHeaders:
      - name: x-b3-sampled
        value: 0
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  timeoutSeconds: 2
  periodSeconds: 10
```

Yet this does not suppress the tracing!! Forgot to mention that we have ISTIO 1.6 and I thought this would suppress the tracing of the healthcheck... Any help please.

Comment: Please open a new question if you have additional issues, asking follow up questions in an answer is not going to be noticed.